# PHP How to check if a string already exists in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a user enter a desired name, then check the database to see if it exists before I make it. It's not working properly though, sometimes it echos the right thing, sometimes not.

```
$makeName = $_POST["userName"];
$nameFind = "SELECT userName FROM usertable WHERE userName = $makeName";
$nameCompare = mysqli_query($con, $nameFind);

if($nameCompare == false)
{
    echo "This is a new name";
}
else
{
    echo "Pick a new name please";
}
```

Comment: [RTFM: `mysqli_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) *doesn't* return a boolean indidicating row count - if it returns false there was an error, or a "result" object otherwise. (Also, the query will always fail as the SQL text will likely certainly be invalid; [*check for errors*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).)

Comment: you need to count the rows, you are currently just seeing if the query is executed successfully

Comment: Google SQL injection. At the very least escape **and** quote your strings in a query, but preferably use prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query doesn't fail just because it returns no rows. Use `mysqli_num_rows()` to find out if there was a match or not.

Also [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/)
[image: xkcd]

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it that way.

Instead,

1. Create a unique constraint on the column "username".
2. Insert the user's desired name.
3. Trap the error when the desired name already exists.

Why? Your approach *always* requires two round-trips to the database, and it doesn't account for errors. And you have to trap errors anyway; there are lots of things that can go wrong with an insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes and escaping:

`"select userName FROM usertable WHERE userName = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($makeName) . "'"`

And then use `mysqli_num_rows()`

`$result = mysqli_query($query); $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($nameCompare))
{
    echo "Pick a new name please";
}
else
{
    echo "This is a new name";
}
```

this will check the result, if there is a row, it's already used.

Answer (score 0):

You need two queries for that anyways

```
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);


 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE username='$username'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
 $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if( $num_row ==1 ) {

        echo 'false';           
    }
    else{       
                $query_insert = "INSERT INTO login (username, password)VALUES ('$username','$password');";

            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query_insert) or die(mysqli_error());
            }
```